# Adding classpath to jetty running in maven integration-test

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, jetty, integration-testing

I'm trying to set up integration tests for a Maven project that produces a war file. (As seen here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin/.) However I the war file requires a bunch of .properties files on the classpath, that I don't want to bundle in the war.

Is there a way (preferably through plugin configuration) to add a folder to the classpath used by jetty?

I Googled this and found http://markmail.org/message/awtqrgxxttra3uxx but this, as far as I can tell, does not actually work at all. The .properties files are not found.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should be possible using the `webAppConfig` configuration element (sample below taken from [this thread](http://markmail.org/thread/zz5gvajlcykf7eb7)):

```
<webAppConfig>
  <contextPath>/nportal</contextPath>
  <!-- All I want to do here is add in the /etc/jetty/classes for runtime files. For some reason I have to also add back in the /target/classes directory -->
  <extraClasspath>${basedir}/target/classes/;${basedir}/etc/jetty/classes/</extraClasspath>
</webAppConfig>
```

Comment: Another maybe more marginal way is to use `<contextXml>jetty-context.xml</contextXml>` where `jetty-context.xml` configures `<Set name="extraClasspath>../my/classes,../my/jars/special.jar</Set>`, see [Using the extraClasspath() method](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading#Using_the_extraClasspath.28.29_method).

Answer (score 16):

If you find that the above solution doesn't work for you, consider including the test classpath into your Jetty configuration.

```
<configuration>
   <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
   ...
</configuration>
```

This will then allow you to place all manner of resources/classes on the test classpath and have them visible to the Jetty server without them creeping into the production code.

Comment: if version 7+ users come looking for an answer, the new option name is `<useTestScope>`. More at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin#Configuring_additional_parameters

Answer (score 5):

You can place your additional configuration files under `/src/test/resources` and set a property `<useTestScope>true</useTestScope>` in the plugin configuration as specified [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal):

**useTestScope**

If true, the classes from testClassesDirectory and dependencies of scope "test" are placed first on the classpath. By default this is false.

Comment: Oh, there's already a comment with the same link... I'll leave the answer — it's more noticeable.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Jetty starts up outputting this: [INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.7.v20160115:start (start-jetty) @ someapp ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: Verizon CHC Timer Server
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = /Users/mvmn/wrkdir/someapp/target/classes
2016-03-01 15:27:55.704:INFO::main: Logging initialized @4023ms
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /Users/mvmn/wrkdir/someapp/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
...

Comment: Doesn't work for me neither. Edit: works with version >= 7.0.0