# Jetty not looking in test-classes directory for resources

Tags: maven, jetty, integration-testing

I am using maven-jetty plugin and when I use jetty to run a webapp, the webapp does not look in the target/test-classes directory at all for a resource. However, it can find resources in the target/classes directory.

Here is the relevant part of my pom.xml

```
<configuration>
 <webApp>target/webapp.war</webApp> 
 <testClassesDirectory>target/test-classes/</testClassesDirectory> 
 <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath> 
 <stopPort>9966</stopPort> 
 <stopKey>stopKey</stopKey> 
</configuration>
```

How can I make the maven-jetty plugin look in target/test-classes for resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `/src/test/java` and `/src/test/resources` folders are only intended for unit testing. They are not added to `maven-jetty-plugin` CLASSPATH nor they are included in resulting WAR.

Comment: So is there a way to make jetty look into my target/test-classes directory?

Comment: Looks like there are some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176067. If you find some of them working, I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have looked at that question before but their solutions do not work for me. The first answer uses $(basedir) in the <extraClassPath> tag, what does the dollar sign mean?

Comment: `$(basedir)` is a placeholder for current project base directory (the one with `src` and `target`). Why it isn't working for you?

Comment: I got it working, the stuff you suggested did not work at first since my goal was "deploy-war", when it would only work for "run". So now it works.

Comment: There's a setting useTestScope that is described this way "If true, the classes from testClassesDirectory and dependencies of scope "test" are placed first on the classpath. By default this is false" (see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html ). The problem is - it doesn't seem to work either.